# Websphere MQ Dead letter queue handler failure

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to create a dead letter queue handler on linux box with following string

```
DEFINE SERVICE(dlqhandler) + CONTROL(MANUAL) + DESCR('DLQ Handler Service') + 
SERVTYPE(SERVER) + STARTCMD('/home/mqm/dlq/dlqhandler.sh') + 
STDOUT('/home/mqm/dlq/dlq.log') + 
STDERR('/home/mqm/dlq/dlq.err') + 
REPLACE
```

However service fails to start. Does any one have any idea about this?

Regards
J

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how the command is executed by WebSphere MQ.  When you execute a text file from a shell program, as a convenience the shell looks for a shebang line at the head of the file for a clue as to what executable to run.  It then runs the specified program and passes the file as an argument.  So, for example, if you run `/home/mqm/dlq/dlqhandler.sh` and the first line in the script is `#! /bin/sh` your shell converts this to `/bin/sh /home/mqm/dlq/dlqhandler.sh` on your behalf and submits it.  The effect is to start a new sub-shell and pass it your script file as an argument.

WebSphere MQ uses the OS to directly execute whatever you put in the `STARTCMD` field.  There is no convenient substitution as performed by the shell so if the thing you specify is a script, the OS doesn't know what to do with it.  Changing to `STARTARG(/bin/sh /home/mqm/dlq/dlqhandler.sh)` won't help because the OS sees this not as a command and an argument but as a command with an embedded space.

However, WebSphere MQ does provide a `STARTARG` parameter for this purpose.  If you change to use the following command (assuming that your script's shebang line executes `/bin.sh`) it should work:

```
DEFINE SERVICE(dlqhandler) + 
       CONTROL(MANUAL) DESCR('DLQ Handler Service') + 
       SERVTYPE(SERVER) STARTCMD('/bin/sh') + 
       STARTARG('/home/mqm/dlq/dlqhandler.sh') +
       STDOUT('/home/mqm/dlq/dlq.log') + 
       STDERR('/home/mqm/dlq/dlq.err') + 
       REPLACE
```

**UPDATE:**
After some testing we discovered that the Linux server was configured to run a restricted shell.  This prevented passing arguments with path names and, relevant to this issue, executing anything hosted on a shared drive such as `/hom/mqm`.  In the restricted environment, moving the scripts and logs to a directory under `/var/mqm` solved the problem.

During the testing we were able to isolate the issue by using shell builtin commands.  These have no path or permission issues so ruled out things like filesystem permissions and so forth.  For example, `STARTCMD('/bin/sh') STARTARG('-c "echo It works"')` told us that the QMgr was able to invoke `/bin/sh` correctly.  Changing the script to a single line that read `echo It works` failed which told us that it wasn't the content of the script but the script itself that was the problem.  Using `STARTARG('-c set')` worked and showed us where the current directory was and the contents of `$PATH`.  Moving the script to the current directory solved the permission problem and some further experimentation showed it wasn't the `/` in the script path that was failing.  The only obvious difference we saw between `/home/mqm` and `/var/mqm` was that one was shared and one was a dedicated mount.  The final service definition was:

```
DEFINE SERVICE(dlqhandler) +
       CONTROL(QMGR) DESCR('DLQ Handler Service') + 
       SERVTYPE(SERVER) STARTCMD('/bin/sh') + 
       STARTARG('-c "+MQ_INSTALL_PATH+bin/runmqdlq < +MQ_DATA_PATH+subdir/+QMNAME+.rules.table"') +
       STDOUT('+MQ_DATA_PATH+subdir/dlq.+QMNAME+.log') + 
       STDERR('+MQ_DATA_PATH+subdir/dlq.+QMNAME+.err') + 
       STOPCMD('+MQ_INSTALL_PATH+bin/amqsstop') +
       STOPARG('-m +QMNAME+ -p +MQ_SERVER_PID+') +
       REPLACE
```

Replace `subdir` above with the path to the rules file.  So for example, `+MQ_DATA_PATH+subdir/+QMNAME+.rules.table` might be `+MQ_DATA_PATH+exits/+QMNAME+.rules.table` which would expect the rules file in `/var/mqm/exits` on stock Linux with default install.

Comment: Hi T.Rob, Many thanks for your answer. When I try to start this service, I get following in the dlq.err suggesting '/bin/sh: /home/mqm/dlq/dlqhandler.sh Permission denied' However if I manually run command in dlqhandler.sh, it works fine. Any idea?

Comment: Hi T.Rob, As per your suggestions, moving files into MQ_DATA_PATH sorted the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Trying to make your final service definition work as it's the first time I've seen an example not using a batch file/shell script in the STARTCMD. Is this really a working example? Not happening for me :-(

Comment: Maybe that's why it got no votes or accept. ;-)  Two problems, both fixed. First, it's `STARTARG` not `STARTARGS` and second, OP had unwrapped lines with embedded continuation chars and I neglected to clean them up. See also official example not using shell script in KC: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q021030_.htm

Comment: The official example you link to is for the trigger monitor and it doesn't need a shell script because it just takes parameters. All the examples I've see for the DLQ Handler use a shell script because of the stdin requirement (I assume) and I was wondering how you'd managed it without. This definitely works for you then?

Comment: Ah, now I see what you are talking about. Wasn't the same as my example in the first answer where I execute `/bin/sh` first. I know I had it working when I updated back in '12 but not sure how I broke it when I pasted the example in.  Managed to capture OPs errors and mine both!  Tested and updated. This one works.